# Convert List<dynamic> to Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: dart

I have this piece of code which works as expected:

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

main(List<String> arguments) async {

 String host = "localhost";
 int port = 5432;
 String dbName = "quakedata";
 String username = "postgres";
 String password = "xxx";

 var connection;

 try {
  connection = PostgreSQLConnection(host, port, dbName, username: username, password: password);
  await connection.open();

  var query = """select geojson from dm_quakefeatures order by modified_date desc limit 10""";

  List<List<dynamic>> results = await connection.query(query);

  for(final row in results){
    for(final thisIsAMap in row){
      print(thisIsAMap);
    }
  }

 } catch (exception, stackTrace) {
   print(exception);
   print(stackTrace);
 } finally {
   connection.close();
 }
}
```

What Im confused about is these two points:

1. According to postgres package [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/postgres/latest/postgres/PostgreSQLConnection-class.html), method `query()` should return  `Future<List<List>>` but returning `List<List<dynamic>>`?
   Why? Is this because of `await`?
2. I know that in `thisIsAMap` variable I wil receive data in this format:

   `{
   "properties": {
   "mag": 1.4,
   "place": "Southern Alaska",
   "time": 1544108572101,
   "updated": 1544108744865,
   "tsunami": 0,
   "type": "earthquake",
   "title": "M 1.4 - Southern Alaska"
   },
   "geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": [
     -149.9893,
     61.4013,
     32.8
   ]
   }
   }`

   which would perfectly fit in `Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>` data type.
   How can I convert this to it?